# Why is finalize not being called?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have couple of questions regarding garbage collector in java.

Q1.As far as I understand, finalize() gets called when object is out of scope and JVM is about to collect garbage. I thought finalize() method is called automatically by garbage collector, but it does not seems to work in this case. What is the explanation? Why is the need for me to explicitly call finalize() method?

```
public class MultipleConstruct {
    int x,y;    
    public MultipleConstruct(int x)
    {
        this.x= x;
        y=5;        
        System.out.println("ONE");
    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.finalize();
        System.out.println("FINALIZED");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        MultipleConstruct construct = new MultipleConstruct(3);
    }
}
```

Q2. Also, when is garbage collector invoked? I understand gc is a daemon thread and invoked by JVM depending on heap size remaining. Does that mean, JVM waits for the program to use threshold limit of resources and then notify the gc to sweep garbage objects.

**EDIT:** How does gc resolved circular references?

Comment: GC is performed whenever the JVM thinks it needs to call it, although IIRC the Oracle JVM will actually call it with a System.gc (). IIRC it's also not guaranteed to be called. For your example, how are you testing to see if/when it's called?

Comment: Don't use finalize() it is in no way equivalent to a C++ destructor.

Comment: @DwB i agree but then what could be a way to implement destructor like behaviour in java i.e bug free resource cleaning.

Comment: Use try {} finally {} blocks for bug free resource cleaning.

Comment: @DWB that is not solution in cases such as u have paint method in an object which has drawn image on screen and now it is out of scope but image is still seen on screen. U need a destructor that will clean image on screen. isn't it?

Comment: There is _no_ guarantee when, if ever, your finalizer will be called.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a lot to finalize() method which is frankly a lot to write, but in short:

An object is in the finalized state if it is still unreachable after its finalize method, if any, has been run. A finalized object is awaiting deallocation. Note that the VM implementation controls when the finalizer is run. You are almost always better off doing your own cleanup instead of relying on a finalizer. Using a finalizer can also leave behind critical resources that won't be recovered for an indeterminate amount of time.

In your case the reason it does not print is that you do not know when the finalizer thread will call the finalize() method. What is happening is that the program is terminating before anything can get printed. To check it:
edit the code inside main code by( NOTE: this does not guarrantee nor should you should ever rely on it but still it does prints some time)

```
for(int i =0;i<1000000;i++)
    {
        MultipleConstruct construct = new MultipleConstruct(3);
        construct = null;
    }
```

There are a lot of disadvantages of using a finalize() right from taking more time in object construction to possibility of memory leakage and memory starvation. If you strongly refer to the same object inside the finalize() then it is never called the second time and thus can leave system in undesired state etc etc etc...
The only place where you should use finalize() is as a safety net to dispose any resources like InputStream uses it to close (which again there is no guarrantee that it will will br run when your program is still alive). Another place to use it is while using natives where garbage collector has no control.

For more info visit:

> http://jatinpuri.com/?p=106

Answer (score 5):

q1) finalize method is called when the object is being garbage collected, thus, if no GC is being performed, your finalizer may not be called. You need to call super simply to preserve the behavior provided by Object implementation.

q2) the exact moment in which GC is performed depends on a lot of factors like: which JVM you are using, tuning parameters, amount of free heap, etc. So it does not only rely on a used heap threshold. You can also ask for a GC to be performed through System.gc() but you have no guarantee about if and when it will be actually executed.
You can find some details on how to configure GC in http://java.sun.com/performance/reference/whitepapers/tuning.html

Answer (score 3):

it gets called *eventually* or not at all

basically the GC scans the heap for everything that is not reachable and runs the finalizer on those (after which it needs to prove again it is not reachable for it to be freed)

however it can take a while (effectively undefined and actually dependent on program behavior) for the GC to find it which is why you shouldn't really rely on it to dispose of critical data

edit: as for circular references it distinguishes between objects with a finalize method and objects without one

for an object to be freed (deleted from main memory) it may not be reachable by any code (this includes finalizers that still need to run)

when 2 objects with finalizers are eligible to get the finalizers run the GC arbitrarily selects one object and runs the finalizer on it and then it can run the other object

note that a finalizer can run while the fields of the objects may or may not be finalized already

Comment: so you mean adding a finalize() method does not ensure bug free cleaning? For e.g in such cases if there is a file object open and I want to clean it before object holding that file object dies then finalize() method is of no use unless explicitly called.

Comment: @prap19 yep this is why `close()` is relied on more than `finalize()`

Comment: close() function in case of object? is that what you mean? AS far the file is considered, that is just an example. I am concerned about destructor like behavior in JAVA

Comment: @prap19 I meant `close()` of the `Closeable` interface, and many times finalize is utterly useless or there is a solution with explicit disposing of resources

Comment: As of Java 7 there's the possibility to use automatic resource management (with `try`), which will automatically call `close()` at the end of the try-block. This will simplify disposing of objects. You shall never use `finalize` for disposing resources.

Comment: There is no special treatment for circular references. That sentence is misleading. JVMs like HotSpot optimize the process for objects with trivial finalize() methods, but that's regardless of the shape of the reference graph. Further, if more than one object is pending for finalization, they may be processed in an arbitrary order *or even concurrently* in multiple finalizer threads.

Answer (score -3):

finalize() method is called  automatically during garbage collection.  System.gc() method forcibly calls garbage collector. but we will have to  destroy object before.
example:

```
     public class Sample 
{
    public Sample()
    {
        System.out.println("Object created");
    }
    @Override
    public void finalize()
    {
        System.out.println("Object Destroyed");
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Sample x=new Sample();
        Sample y=new Sample();

        x=null;
        y=null;

        System.gc();
    }
}
```

Comment: System.gc() cannot force JVM to run garbage collector. It only informs JVM that objects are open for collections.

Comment: `System.gc()` does not force garbage collection.  It note that garbage collection is desired, but the JVM will run garbage collection only when it wants to run it.

Comment: point lies here that the objects must be made 'null' or destroyed  to see the finalize method being called(as shown in above code).Else the finalize method will be called by JVM whenever garbage collection takes place .

Comment: Even when `System.gc()` triggers a garbage collection, there's no guaranty to see the effect of the `finalize()` method (in fact, it's rather unlikely in this example), as finalization happens asynchronously *after* the garbage collector has enqueued the objects and here, the JVM exits right after the garbage collection.

Comment: It depens on how the JVM has been setup as well. -XX:DisableExplicitGC JVM flag can be used to configure if explicit System.gc() would have any effect or not.