# Is there a callback for when a `RecylerView.ViewHolder` instance should be GC'd?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

```kotlin
class MyRecyclerViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


  fun onBind(data: Data) {
    // launching an asynchronous action
  }
}
```

I need to cancel the async action I'm launching when `onBind(..)` is called again on the same `MyRecyclerViewHolder` instance, or if `MyRecyclerViewHolder` is ready to be GC'd for whatever reason.

Obviously I can identify when `onBind(..)` is called again, but how can I register to be made aware of when the `MyRecyclerViewHolder(..)` instance is ready for GC so I can cancel the async action?

EDIT: Another way to think about this is that imagine that `ViewHolder` had the following API:

```kotlin
interface ViewHolder {

  // because you have constructor access, there's no need for `onCreate(..)`

  // may be called multiple times
  fun onBind(data: Data)

  fun onDestroy() // called once when it is no longer relevant
}
```

How can I be notified that my `ViewHolder` should be "destroyed" - aka it is no longer relevant for the UI?

Answer (score 0):

You are maybe looking for something like this:

```
override fun onViewAttachedToWindow(holder: Type) {
}

override fun onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder: Type) {
}
```

The `onViewAttachedToWindow` will be called everytime the viewholder gets in the screen. The `onViewDetachedFromWindow` will be called everytime the viewholder gets off the screen.

Comment: Looking at the docs

> Becoming detached from the window is not necessarily a permanent condition  the consumer of an Adapter's views may choose to cache views offscreen while they are not visible, attaching and detaching them as appropriate.

I think I would to actually want to keep this asynchronous action running while the views are detached but still cached, as they could become relevant again?

Comment: @ZakTaccardi I had to do something like this recently. I triggered a download in a viewholder and had an observer that everytime was called it updates a progress bar, what I did is that I stopped observing and start observing when these methods were called. 

It will depend on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use Object.finalize method but it's not guaranteed to be called:

[Why is finalize not being called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7786946/why-is-finalize-not-being-called)